# How would I be able to pass an array to a ComboBox after reading it from a csv file?

Tags: java, javafx

So far I'm trying to pass an array so I can pass it to a ComboBox but am currently stuck on trying to figure out why it doesn't seem to be showing up without giving me an error, Im a newbie at this and having a hard time trying to grasp what am i doing wrong on my code.

```
package lab2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import static java.nio.file.Files.lines;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import static java.util.Arrays.sort;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;


public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    
    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML 
    private Label stateLabel;
    @FXML 
    private Label zipcodeLabel;
    @FXML 
    private Label timezoneLabel;
    
    
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<CityData> selectCityCombo;
    @FXML
    private ArrayList<String> CityData;
    
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }
    @FXML // handles the action to read csv file when read button is clicked
    private List<List<String>> readFromFile(ActionEvent event){
        List<List<String>> listOfCityData = new ArrayList<>();
        
        try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (new File("CityData2.csv")))) {
               String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                System.out.println(line);
               String[] values = line.split(",");
                listOfCityData.add(Arrays.asList(values));
                
                }               
        } catch (IOException e ) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Error File Not Correctly Read");
            }
        return listOfCityData;
    };
    @FXML//Grabs the data from the csv data array created and sends it to the comboBox to display
    private void selectCityCombo(ActionEvent event) {
        CityData sel =  selectCityCombo.getValue();
        
        stateLabel.setText("State:           " + sel.getState());
        zipcodeLabel.setText("Zipcode:      " + sel.getZipcode());
        timezoneLabel.setText("Timezone:        " + sel.getTimezone());
    }
    
    CityData listOfCityData[] = {
        new CityData()
    };
   
    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Arrays.toString(listOfCityData));
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
       
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfCityData.length; i++)
            selectCityCombo.getItems().add(listOfCityData[i]);
    }    
    
}
```

This is what I've come up so far but I cant seem to figure out how to pass the listOfCityData as an array towards the CityData listOfCityData[] array in order for it to pass into the selectCityCombo

Answer (score 0):

You have most of the right code, but you need to do it in the correct order and link the ObservableList to the ComboBox `yourComboBox.setItems(...)`.

This line looks like your biggest issue:
`ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Arrays.toString(listOfCityData));`
It will be empty when your code first starts because `listOfCityData` is empty. Once you fix that and link the box as mentioned above then you should be back in business.

For example, the following shows a correct order and is linked to the ComboBox:

```
    //Create empty list to be used for ComboBox selection
    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    //Link empty ObservableList to the ComboBox
    selectCityCombo.setItems(list);

    //Then the readFromFile method could look something like this
    private List<String> readFromFile(){
        //Create intermediate list
        List<String> listOfCityData = new ArrayList<>();
        
        //Read the data in
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (new File("CityData2.csv")))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i <values.length; i++)
            {
                //Add each item to the intermediate list
                listOfCityData.add(line[i]);
            }
        }
        return listOfCityData;
    }

    //Finally none of this will work unless you call the readFromFile method during initialize, or you could call it from a button event
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        
        //Call the readFromFile method and get the data
        List<String> listOfCityData = readFromFile();

        //Now update the ObservableList:
        list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Arrays.toString(listOfCityData));

        //Alternatly you could link the list to the ComboBox here
        selectCityCombo.setItems(list);
    }
```